# dtexec run with error : Cannot load script for execution

Tags: ssis

I am trying to test run a simple SSIS script task on another machine for testing deployment. However, it gives the following error when using dtexec command line program

Description: Cannot load script for execution.

I have rebuilt the SSIS solution in Visual Studio 2019 community already. Do I need to copy the other files beside the Package.dtsx?

Comment: The error message, it could be because of version mismatch or a missing DLL. Is there any other information in the error? What does the Script task do? Is it calling external dependencies?

You should only need to copy the dtsx-file - the Script task is included in the SSIS package.

Comment: It is just the default one. I created an empty SSIS project with just one script task, by dragging the script task to the control flow.. Then built and copied to the other server for testing. I did go into to edit the script task and built

Comment: Did you ever solve this?